# Localstorage is cleared after the angular update

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a android ionic cordova application that uses angular 9, and I am saving some values in the application for the later use in local storage. But after angular 12 upgrade, while I update the application from playstore(without uninstall the old app, updating new app), the local storage is cleared. As part of the Angular 12 upgrade, the **@ionic/storage** node module is updated to **@ionic/storage-angular**, this is the only change done as part of this. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this happen on all platforms?

Comment: this is only issue in the android. ios this is working fine

Comment: Hello, I am also facing this problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Pierre not yet